# Add UIImageview in Uitextview as in iMessage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitextview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UItextview` and adding an extra `inputAccessoryview` for toolbar buttons to perform additional actions.
My toolbar has a camera icon which gets the image from `UIImagePickerController` and Ι have to add this image in my `UItextview`.

Right now Ι am able to do this with :

```
[myTextView addSubView:imageView];
```

But that way, always adds the image at the beginning of the textview and what Ι want is to add it at the current cursor location. I would also like to remove this image just like I remove the text from textview.

Just for the record, Ι also tried getting `UItextview` text's selected range and tried inserting my `imageview` at that location but it did not work.

Edited Code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * mas = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.commentsTextView.text];
NSRange cursorPoistion = [self.commentsTextView selectedRange];

UIImage *chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSTextAttachment* onionatt = [NSTextAttachment new];
onionatt.image = chosenImage;
onionatt.bounds = CGRectMake(0,-5,200,200);
NSAttributedString* onionattchar = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:onionatt];

[mas insertAttributedString:onionattchar atIndex:(cursorPoistion.location + cursorPoistion.length)];

self.commentsTextView.attributedText = mas;
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to remove the image?

Answer (score 8):

This was impossible before iOS 7. Now, in iOS 7, you can do it because UITextView is based on Text Kit and inline images are possible in an NSAttributedString.

Here's a very simple example where I add a picture of onions just after the word "Onions" in my text (`mas` is my NSMutableAttributedString):

```
UIImage* onions = [self thumbnailOfImageWithName:@"onion" extension:@"jpg"];

NSTextAttachment* onionatt = [NSTextAttachment new];
onionatt.image = onions;
onionatt.bounds = CGRectMake(0,-5,onions.size.width,onions.size.height);
NSAttributedString* onionattchar = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:onionatt];

NSRange r = [[mas string] rangeOfString:@"Onions"];
[mas insertAttributedString:onionattchar atIndex:(r.location + r.length)];

self.tv.attributedText = mas;
```

That's for a small inline image. It sounds like you want to add your image in a paragraph of its own, but the principle is exactly the same.

Comment: That's better but it still doesn't let me add multiple images. Also when i add the next image it pushed the text to the left. I want a hard return when ever there is an image. See my edit above to see the code i am using